# Making a user control invisible

Tags: c#, user-controls

In a c# code behind of a user control, how can i make the control invisible based on the value of a public property?

Let's say my user control is like so and contains content:

```
<Ctrl:ComponentChecker ID="ComponentChecker" runat="server" MakeInvisible="Yes">
<p>This is my content...</p>
</Ctrl:ComponentChecker>
```

My code behind is something like this:

```
public class ComponentChecker : AbstractController
{
public string MakeInvisible { get; set; }

protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    if (MakeInvisible != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(MakeInvisible) && MakeInvisible == "Yes")
    {
        //Hide the user control
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? I need to inherit from `AbstractController` for some other logic. After some reading online, inheriting from `Placeholder` and then `this.Visible = false` does the trick but I can't do that in my case.

Comment: can you explain  why you  can't do that  in your case

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a user control with content.

Comment: try this..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774983/c-sharp-create-invisible-user-control?rq=1

Comment: Julie, how do you mean? In that conditional statement what would the syntax be for me to make the control invisible?